# Passing parameters to a PHP file through URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, url, parameters

The data we want to send: parameter code with value A123,
parameter price with value 12.45, and parameter date with value 12-3-2016.
Assume that the server-side data processing file is called computePrice.php, and
the domain of the server is www.mydomain.com.

My guess is www.mydomain.com?code=A123&price=12.45&date=12-3-2016

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to write the URL value to a string variable called myurl in order to pass the data?

Comment: I guess your guess is about right. Why do you ask? Didn't you try it yet?

Comment: I don't know where to include the computePrice.php file in the URL. Do I need it?

Answer (score 0):

You can take those URL values using $_GET. Do this like so:

```
<?php
$code = $_GET['code'];
$price = $_GET['price'];
$date = $_GET['date'];
?>
```

Make sure when you redirect to that page you run a urlencode() on each variable. For example:

```
<?php
$code = "A123";
$price = "12.45";
$date = "12-3-2016";
$url = "www.mydomain.com?code=".urlencode($code)."&price=".urlencode($price)."&date=".urlencode($date);
header('Location: '.$url);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use the URL www.mydomain.com/computePrice.php?code=A123&price=12.45&date=12-3-2016

This will pass all of these values to computePrice.php